# PHP ignores its php.ini in Windows

Tags: php, windows, settings, php-ini

I use `PHP` on my Windows host system for `composer`. After a failed attempt to add `parse/php-sdk` to a project (since the SDK needs the PHP cURL module to be enabled), I updated the PHP settings. But it didn't solve the problem. Then I checked, whether the `php.ini` settings are correct:

```
C:\Users\me>php --info | grep "extension_dir"
extension_dir => ext => ext
C:\Users\me>php --info | grep "php.ini"
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File => C:\Program Files\php-5.6.8-Win32-VC11-x64\php.ini
```

Yes, they are. There is no `C:\Windows\php.ini`, but it doesn't matter -- the `C:\Program Files\php-5.6.8-Win32-VC11-x64\php.ini` is the file I updated and it's loaded.

Then I printed the modules list (`php --modules`) and noticed, that it has nothing in common with the extensions setting in the loaded `php.ini`. I also tried to change other settings (like `memory_limit`), but PHP seems to ignore my `php.ini` and load the configurations from somewhere else.

How to detect this magical "somewhere" (means: where PHP actually loads its settings from) and how to make it load the wished settings from the defined file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Composer install error - requires ext\_curl when it's actualy enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335305/composer-install-error-requires-ext-curl-when-its-actualy-enabled)

Comment: @uri2x Thanks for you comment. No, this question doesn't duplicate the one you linked to. Actually it's not about composer, it's about PHP on Windows.

Comment: That's interesting we are using sort of the same setup where we are updating the Loaded Configuration file and that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was updating the wrong file;
i first run the editor as an administrator, then updated the php config file
[image]

then i activated the extension

[image]

i checked that the module is activated using:

```
php -m
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The problem is caused by the fact, that php.ini is being edited by editor that wasn't run with elevated privileges. If the PHP folder sits inside "Program Files", you have to access the files within it with admin privileges.
I discovered the unbelievable fact, that the changes aren't saved into the php.ini despite the editor shows them correctly, even if closed/opened!
This can be simply verified by checking php.ini content - run `more "C:\Program Files\...  ...\php.ini"` from the command line.

The solution is obvious - you have to run the editor with elevated privileges, or grant user permissions to the folder with php.ini and then edit it.