# stripe/stripe-php v7.117.0 requires ext-curl * but it is not present

Tags: php, composer-php, stripe-payments

hello i am trying to learn web development, for this, I had learned php and now am working with Codeigniter 4. I am trying to integrate Stripe with Codeigniter Application which i am developing, i am trying to install stripe library via composer with this command **

> composer require stripe/stripe-php

** but it giving me the following error

---

> [InvalidArgumentException]
> Package stripe/stripe-php has requirements incompatible with your PHP
> versi     on, PHP extensions and Composer version:
> - stripe/stripe-php v7.117.0 requires ext-curl * but it is not present. stripe/stripe-php v7.117.0 requires ext-curl * but it is not
> present.

---

how i can solve this error an install stripe library via composer. thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to install it ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335305/composer-install-error-requires-ext-curl-when-its-actually-enabled

Comment: @Lenny4 yes but when i tried that curl installing command i get this error E: Unable to locate package php-curl

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install php-curl`